# Using RewriteRule to write URL from page/unique_id to page.php?id=unique_id

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to format my URL from `http://jacqueskoekemoer.co.za/article/5` to `http://jacqueskoekemoer.co.za/article?i=5` where `i` would be the article ID in the database.

Currently [this URL](http://jacqueskoekemoer.co.za/article?i=5) works. But [this one](http://jacqueskoekemoer.co.za/article/5) does not. It does change the url to `article.php` but it doesn't add the query string to the end.

I know this because it does not appear in `print_r($_REQUEST);` or `print_r($_GET);`

What am I doing wrong in my `.htaccess` file, or can you suggest other resources that I could look at to resolve the problem?

I have used the following 2 URL's primarily to get the RewriteRule working.

[URL 1](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

[URL 2](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

In `.htaccess` file the rule rewrite section looks like this:
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^article/$ article.php?i=$1 [L] # Handle requests for "article"
#RewriteRule ^article/$/ article.php?i=$1 [NC,L] # Handle requests for "article"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)$ article.php?i=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: If I now wanted to add a second URL to also be rewritten I assume that I would need to add a line underneath the article line like this:
RewriteRule ^kb/(\d+)$ kb.php?tags=$1 [L]

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer Correct.